# When the iPhone hasn't been turned on for a while, the apps will "update twice"?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

Let's say if I have an older iPhone I haven't turned on for a few months.

I noticed all the apps: YouTube, Pokemon Go, Google Chrome, they all have the "Update" button for me to update once, and then it changes to "Open", but if I tap on it to get to the app detail page, then it says "Update" again.

And the 2nd Update is the final one.

So what is this Update twice mechanism?  Why can't it just update once to the latest?

P.S. many of these apps have frequent updates. So for example, Pokemon Go probably has an update once per month or 6 weeks, so if the iPhone hasn't been turned on for 6 months, there probably are 4 to 6 updates already, not just two.

Comment: It's possible that one update was already queued up, and that update might not have been the most recent one by the time your phone turned on. Without knowing the specific versions of each intermediary it's hard to know more.

Comment: @Ezekiel is mostly correct here.  To be accurate, *it depends on the code*.  A dev could check the app on start up and if the latest version is greater than the current version, it would trigger an update regardless of the versions between the two.  Alternatively, it could step through each version.  Here’s [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13436573) that shows the latter.

Comment: @Ezekiel so you can say it is a bug. When you are going to update to 2.5 and you follow what the queue says and update to 2.1 and then once again to 2.5, then the update to 2.1 is redundant and is a bug